# Rabl Api and preventing code duplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, api, rabl

I am working on a simple API for a rails project which should also be able for versioning.
I am using rabl-rails gem.

To prevent code duplication, I wanna be able to use my ControllerActions (ex. UserController#search) twice. One time for the normal WebUsers, and one for the API.

I only saw people writing controllers like this:

```
class Api::v1::UsersController
  def list
    @user = User.all
  end
end
```

Do I have to Namespace Controllers for RABL?
Or is it possible to "route or delegate" my JSON requests to existing Controllers?

For example my regular `UsersController` Action "list" has actually this:

```
def list
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json  { render @user }
  end
end
```

`views/users/list.json.rabl` also exist and works well in this case.

**Now I try to move the rabl files into**

`/api/v1/users/list.json.rabl`

I provide a Route:

```
namespace :api, :defaults => {:format => :json} do
  namespace :v1 do
    match 'users/list', to: 'Users#list', as: 'users', via: [:get, :post]
  end
end
```

At the moment I do not provide a Api::V1::UsersController.

**What is the best approach to**

- provide a /api/v1/users/list route but
- use the regular UsersController and
- have the list.json.rabl view in the /api/v1/ folder?

*I hope it's not to complicated explained...*

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue now and was about to post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with the idea, that an API should have his own logic. Some actions have view specific stuff (breadcrumbs, dropdown values, etc.) inside.

With my knowledge "search logic" can be extracted into a module which gets mixed into your ApplicationController class (inlcude). Then you can use this logic in both places: Api and regular web view.

My first attempt is here:

## BaseController

```
# Base Controller for all Api requests

class Api::V1::BaseController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User
end
```

## Api SubControllers

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::V1::BaseController
# Inherit from BaseController -------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       

  # your personal extracted logic
  include SearchLogic

  def list
    @user  = User.all
  end 
end
```

So

Comment: This looks like what I would like to go with. Where do you put `SearchLogic`? in `/lib` or elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, I have also read that ```/lib``` is "the" place. It seems that Rails 4 has added new require paths called "concerns" (see here: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/f6bbc3f582bfc16da3acc152c702b04102fcab81#diff-fe18f3d1547d462665ccd5f7e540aa90L50 ) . One for ```controllers``` one for ```models```. I thought for upward compatibility (working on 3.2 right noew) I simply add these paths in my application.rb I wrote this: ```config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/controllers/concerns # config.root}app/models/concerns")```.

Comment: I am on Rails 4 actually. Most of the stuff on the net still is largely rails 3 oriented :) 
On Rails 4, do I need to add to `config.autoload_paths` ? I moved my file from `/lib` to `controllers/concerns`, but only when I do a `require 'my_file.rb'` it works. Examples on the net don't show them using `require 'my_file.rb'`.

Comment: I agree. With ```include``` and ```extend``` methods are threadened like actions. I have no solution for this right now. But I am working on it.